# Templated definitions of operator overloads

Tags: templates, c++11, sfinae

I have some function objects, each of which defines various two-argument overloads of operator():

```
class Foo {};
class Bar {};

struct Functor1 {
    double operator()(const Foo &, const Bar &)  { return 2.2; }
    double operator()(const Bar &, const Foo &)  { return 3.1; }
};

struct Functor2 {
    int operator()(const Foo &, const Foo &)  { return 2; }
    int operator()(const Bar &, const Bar &)  { return 3; }
};
```

Now what I want to do is write a utility that lets me attach these functors, one by one, to a binary operator.  Here is my attempt:

```
#define ATTACH_FUNCTOR_TO_OPERATOR(OPERATOR, FUNCTOR) \
    template<typename Operand1, typename Operand2> \
    decltype(FUNCTOR(std::declval<Operand1>(), std::declval<Operand2>())) \
    operator OPERATOR(const Operand1 &operand1, const Operand2 &operand2) { \
        return FUNCTOR(operand1, operand2); \
    }
```

It works okay the first time:

```
ATTACH_FUNCTOR_TO_OPERATOR(+, Functor1());
```

but when I add a second invocation with the same operator:

```
ATTACH_FUNCTOR_TO_OPERATOR(+, Functor2());
```

then Visual Studio 2013 tells me "function template has already been defined".

Notice that, for any pair of operands, there is only one instance of + whose return type `decltype(FUNCTOR(std::declval<Operand1>(), std::declval<Operand2>()))` can be resolved to any particular type.  I expected any other attempted instantiations to fail silently and not cause any trouble -- aka SFINAE.

I have also tried various styles of `enable_if`, without success.

Is there a legal way to do this in standard C++11?

Is there a way that works in VS2013?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but shouldn't it be `ATTACH_FUNCTOR_TO_OPERATOR(+, Functor1)` (without parentheses)?

Comment: Nevermind, I misread the code. Could be a compiler bug..

Answer (score 4):

This is a [known bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/753170/cannot-overload-template-functions-differing-only-by-unknown-type-return-type) in VC++.  We can reduce it to the following self-contained example:

```
template<typename T> void f(decltype(T::a)) {}
template<typename T> void f(decltype(T::b)) {}
```

> source_file.cpp(2) : error C2995: 'void f(unknown-type)' : function
>   template has already been defined
>           source_file.cpp(1) : see declaration of 'f'

The issue appears to be that VC++ considers "*unknown-type*" types (i.e., those from `decltype`) to be equivalent for the purpose of determining whether a function template definition is a redefinition.

One workaround is to disambiguate the templates with a unique, unused type:

```
#define ATTACH_FUNCTOR_TO_OPERATOR(OPERATOR, FUNCTOR) \
    template<typename Operand1, typename Operand2> \
    typename std::conditional<true, \
        decltype(FUNCTOR(std::declval<Operand1>(), std::declval<Operand2>())), \
        std::integral_constant<int, __LINE__>>::type \
    operator OPERATOR(const Operand1 & operand1, const Operand2 &operand2) { \
        return FUNCTOR(operand1, operand2); \
    }
```

Comment: Ah, I thought about using tag dispatching to disambiguate, but for some reason I though it wouldn't work with the operator in the OPs code. Nice workaround, bad bug :)

Comment: And once again, as your link to Microsoft connect shows, Microsoft seems to be ignoring the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  It solved the problem as stated, however it leads to failures at sites where I try to use the operator normally, i.e. where it doesn't match any of my own overloads.  I will work on constructing some clean example code.

Comment: Update: it's all good.  I just need to stick very close to what you've written.  (I had been defining the result type as a defaulted third template parameter on line one of the macro, and using that template param as the return type on line 2; and I added your std::conditional maneouvre on line 2.  That wasn't close enough.)

Answer (score 2):

The following simplified sample compiles fine in ideone and returns the right results, so I can only imagine it to be some kind of VS2013 bug. However I'm no C++-standard expert so I don't know if the compiler is required to handle this scenario.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

class Foo {};
class Bar {};

struct Functor1
{
    static double functor(const Foo &) { return 2.2; }
};

struct Functor2
{
    static int functor(const Bar &) { return 3; }
};

template<typename Operand>
auto test(const Operand &operand) -> decltype(Functor1::functor(operand))
{
    return Functor1::functor(operand);
}

template<typename Operand>
auto test(const Operand &operand) -> decltype(Functor2::functor(operand))
{
    return Functor2::functor(operand);
}

int main()
{
    cout << test(Foo()) << endl << test(Bar());
    return 0;
}
```

If I compile it in VS2013 I get the same error: "function template has already been defined". This error shows up even when the template is never instantiated in the whole program. I can only assume the compiler doesn't even try to find the right overload.

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to come up with a solution yet, using `enable_if` seems to fail out of the same reasons.

See also: http://ideone.com/JbDKDF

#### Edit

I found a similar question with a very interesting answer:

[VS2012 SP1 (+november pack) unknown-type errors (alike C::a(T &&...) )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648434/vs2012-sp1-november-pack-unknown-type-errors-alike-cat)